# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have this error in my terminal:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

I'm trying to test the call to an API, but the error appears.

My function:

```
itemToForm = () => {
    this.api.send(this.component, 'get',
        { lang: 'ES', filter: { id: this.item['id'] } }
    ).then(resEsp => {
        this.item = resEsp['data'][0];
        this.api.send(this.component, 'get',
            { lang: 'EN', filter: { id: this.item['id'] } }
        ).then(res => {
            let itemEng = res['data'][0];
            let fields = this.formDef.map(register => register.filter(
                field => field['register_table'].indexOf('traduction') !== -1
            ).map(
                field => field['field_name'])
            ).filter(register => register.length);

            fields = fields.length ? fields[0] : [];

            if (itemEng) {
                this.item = Object.keys(itemEng).reduce((obj, key) => {
                    obj[key] = this.item[key];
                    if (fields.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                        obj[key + '_eng'] = itemEng[key];
                    }
                    return obj;
                }, {});
            }

            if (this.item) {
                this.setForm();
            }
        })
    })
}
```

My specification file:

```
it('should call api.send', () => {
    let spy1 = spyOn(api, 'send');
    let item = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test',
    }

    component.addItem(item);
    component.itemToForm();

    expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: seems like `this.item` isn't initialized yet in line 2 of your snippet. Or `resEsp['data']` doesn't contain any elements, thus `this.item =  resEsp['data'][0];` will set `this.item` again to undefined, which will throw an error in line 4 of your snippet.

Comment: an index.ts file might also be the culprit. try to import directly (without using index.ts files) and see if the error resolves.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**What is happening:**

The function `itemToForm()` is being called before the `this.item` is ready.

**There are many strategies to avoid this error.** A very simple one is to add a catcher at the beginning of the function, like this:

```
itemToForm = () => {
  if(this.item === undefined) {return}
         
  // The rest of the code
}
```

This stops the function, if the data does not exist yet.

**A more elegant solution** may be to go further up in your order of operations, and find who is calling `itemToForm()` and ensure the data exists prior to calling.

Comment: Perfect!
On Vue - with Vuetify - the issue occurs inside the library when we use a watch. Your solution protect from the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I bumped to this question but my issue was actually something completely different.

In my code for some reasons I had

```js
import { SOME_OBJECT } from '.';
```

which should instead be like this:

```js
import { SOME_OBJECT } from './proper-file';
```

Comment: Same here. Angular was blowing up in a random component saying cannot read property of undefined. Turns out, the import path was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error *"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spec')"* when attempting to install a local npm module with `npm install [path to module here]`.

The source of the problem: I hadn't given the local module a name in its *package.json* file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was similar, but I got a different solution as I was using the body-parser module in the JavaScript file.

I had to add

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript version error
in package.json change typescript version to,

"typescript": "3.8.3"

then
npm install