# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

When I try to call the firebase Realtime database it gives me this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')
```

I am writing a code for matching the model text from my code to firebase Realtime database model text
My database Structure:-

```js
{
070921210001{
"Model": "modelName"
}
}
```

and here is How i call my database i have already import all the getDatabase and all :-

```js
  var modelTxt = this.state.models
      console.log(modelTxt)

     
      const dbRef = ref(getDatabase(`/`));
      dbRef.orderByChild(`Model`).equalTo(modelTxt).once("value", function(snapshot){
        console.log(snapshot.val())
      
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Comment: You can see my whole code hearer https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-goodall-c003j?file=/src/App.js

Comment: can you try handling with if statement like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69280349/15774176..does it work?