# TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined reading '2'

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I am losing my mind, respectfully.

I am currently coding an assignment for my studies. I have to call an API using the async fetch method in Javascript using the Svelte framework. This is what i have in my app.svelte.

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>

<title>Sollicitatie Opdracht Volcano</title>

<link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'>

<script defer src='/build/bundle.js'>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    const searchAnime = async () => {
        var response = await fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?q=jujutsu', {
            method: 'GET'
        });
        var result = await response.json();
        return result;
    }

    let aniSearchPromise = searchAnime();

</script>

<h1>API Fetching System</h1>


<main>  
{#await aniSearchPromise}
    <h2>Laden. . .</h2>
{:then data}
    <h2>{data.results[0]}</h2>
{:catch err}
    <h2>Error while loading data.</h2>
{/await}
</main>

<svelte:head>
    <title>aniAPI Test App</title>
</svelte:head>

<style>
    main {
        background-color: lavenderblush;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
</style>
```

I am getting an error at

### data.results[0]

I have no clue how to fix this as I can see that the promise is listed as fulfilled. On data.results[data[2]] is all the fetched data. See screenshot below
[image: Screenshot]

Would anyone be able to explain what is happening and why it is undefined? Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959632/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-id)

Comment: looks like there's no `results` in that object - you probably want `data[2]` instead of `data.results[2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.Results` is not an array and and by seeing your object, probably `data.Results` does not exist here. In your object, data is an array so it should be used like `data[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that data has no attribute called `results` in your screenshot. Can't you just call `data[0]` or `data[2]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Api works correctly, probably you are trying to get data before it fetches

```js
var response = fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?q=jujutsu', {
  method: 'GET'
}).then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
  console.log('Data [0] result', result.data[0]);
})
```