# Page not displaying on Chrome MacOS

Tags: google-chrome, caching, mean-stack

I have a website that is in production using the MEAN stack. One issue is that the chrome will display one of my new pages as a blank screen, even after I hard refresh. However, I can see the page in Firefox and other browsers.

This has become a problem for existing users of my website who are now seeing just a blank screen. Is there a way I can code something to prevent this from happening entirely?

To provide more context this is a page where we're grabbing user data from the API and displaying it. The data being form data such as email, name, etc.

```
main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enabled')
    at template (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:545543)
    at Gv.runInContext (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:61874)
    at Zv (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:64106)
    at fy (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:73306)
    at py (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:74492)
    at fI (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:74356)
    at gy (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:74633)
    at fy (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:74017)
    at py (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:74492)
    at hy (main.84165a1abe8e797f.js:1:74326)
```

This error is displaying in the console about 5 times.

Comment: Did you try looking at stuff like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959632/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-id. Also try disabling GPU rasterization in chrome://flags. Who knows what could be causing it at this point? Also, if you displayed your code I might be able to help you better

Comment: There is no way anyone will be able to go off of a minified stack trace to debug your issue without source code or a link to your live website. [MRE.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

Chrome on MacOS (computer and phone) uses a mac specific engine/webkit for rendering.

A recent update looks to have broke custom CSS "display" values.

Try changing any display values to the standard "block", "inline" etc and see if that helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).